# unable to change site collection administrator after sharepoint 2010 to 2010 migration using content db

Tags: site-collection, migration

I used content db approach for migrating sharepoint 2010 from one server to another.

1.i created new web application on target server.
2.Installed all WSP's on target server.
3. Test-spcontentdatabase powershell( No errors).
4. Mounted database to new web application successfully.

when i go in central admin, change site collection administrator, i can see both site collection which should be but i am unable to select root site collection. when i select it, it doesn't show any details as well but i can select other site collection which resides at wildcard \sites.

any idea?

Comment: When you created the new web application, did you created the root site collection too ? If yes, did you remove the newly created content database before attaching the backup ? Also, any issues/warnings when attaching the database ?

Comment: Have you tried to update the sitecoll administrator using Powershell?

Comment: @vipul. i din't created root site collection. also no warnings during test-content database either.

Comment: @user19952 yes but it throws error as owner is null something

Comment: Could you add the error message you get from powershell?